# Escrita no TextBox congela o formulário

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Tenho um formulário que possui um TextBox e gostaria de escrever nele mas dar um efeito de *typewriter* para que o texto não seja adicionado totalmente "seco".

Criei um método que recebe o texto que eu gostaria de adicionar e faz o efeito como esperado. Todavia, o formulário fica **congelado** e somente após terminar a escrita de todo o texto é possível utilizar o formulário.

```
    private void escreverMensagem(string msg)
    {
        char[] msg_array = msg.ToArray<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < msg_array.Length; i++)
        {
            txtMensagens.AppendText(msg_array[i].ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
    }
```

Quando eu precisar de adicionar algo eu irei apenas chamar ele com a string desejada.

Acredito que devo iniciar uma Thread nova para fazer o método **escreverMensagem(string msg)**, mas não tenho ideia de como ficaria.

Comment: O `Thread.Sleep` está usando a mesma thread da visual. Na chamada do `escreverMensagem` você deve executá-lo de uma outra thread.

Comment: @vnbrs Nesse caso toda vez que eu chamar escreverMensagem eu terei que instanciar uma Thread?

Comment: Se ela for executada na mesma thread em que é desenhada sua tela, vai travar.